# reportlab: how to set initial/default view?

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

I've managed to successfully generate an empy PDF, but it doesn't set the initial view. I'd like to set the initial view to "full view" i.e. the end user see one page fits the PDF reader (= an A4 page fits in the screen).

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf; charset=utf-8')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=""'

    p = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=A4, )
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    return response
```

How to set the default zoom view (if it's possible) with reportlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In short

Add this line:

```
p.setViewerPreference("FitWindow", "true")
```

### Explain

Set viewer preference with:

> ```
> def setViewerPreference(self,pref,value):
>     set one of the allowed enbtries in the documents viewer preferences
> ```

Available `pref` and `value` are:

> ```
> class ViewerPreferencesPDFDictionary(CheckedPDFDictionary):
>     validate=dict(
>         HideToolbar=checkPDFBoolean,
>         HideMenubar=checkPDFBoolean,
>         HideWindowUI=checkPDFBoolean,
>         FitWindow=checkPDFBoolean,
>         CenterWindow=checkPDFBoolean,
>         DisplayDocTitle=checkPDFBoolean,    #contributed by mark Erbaugh
>         NonFullScreenPageMode=checkPDFNames(*'UseNone UseOutlines UseThumbs UseOC'.split()),
>         Direction=checkPDFNames(*'L2R R2L'.split()),
>         ViewArea=checkPDFNames(*'MediaBox CropBox BleedBox TrimBox ArtBox'.split()),
>         ViewClip=checkPDFNames(*'MediaBox CropBox BleedBox TrimBox ArtBox'.split()),
>         PrintArea=checkPDFNames(*'MediaBox CropBox BleedBox TrimBox ArtBox'.split()),
>         PrintClip=checkPDFNames(*'MediaBox CropBox BleedBox TrimBox ArtBox'.split()),
>         PrintScaling=checkPDFNames(*'None AppDefault'.split()),
>         )
> ```

#### Reference

- [ReportLab API Reference](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-reference.pdf)
- [ViewerPreferencesPDFDictionary](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/ddf3d4f5066a03ca4bf9de7942ab28fb4eeb862e/src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#pdfdoc.py-723)

Comment: I didn't test with actual files, but I return the PDF through my `response`. In my case, none of the options are applied (I've tried all of them, settings either true or false and nothing happens)....

Comment: I think this may be in the configuration of the PDF reader itself, I've given up on that (like a lot of other stuff in the messy reportlab domain).